# Spark Dataframe, add new column with function using other columns

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

In my scala program, I have a dataframe `df` with two columns `a` and `b` (both of type `Int`). Aside I have a previously defined object `obj` with some methods and attributes. Here I want to add a new column to my dataframe `df` using the current values of the dataframe and attributes from `obj`.

For example, if I have the dataframe below :

```scala
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 |
+---+---+
```

and if `obj` has an attribute `num: Int = 10` as well as a method `f(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {a + b - this.num}`, I want to use `f` to create the new column `c` like so :

```scala
+---+---+-----+
| a | b |  c  |
+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 0 | -9  |
| 4 | 8 |  2  |
| 2 | 5 | -3  |
+---+---+-----+
```

So the idea is: for each row, take the values of columns `a` and `b` and call the method `f` on `obj` with `a` and `b` as arguments too get the value that we then store in the corresponding row of the new column `c`. I tried to do something like this :

```scala
df = df.withColumn("c", obj.f(col("a"), col("b")))
```

but obviously it doesn't work as `col()` return a column and not the elements of that column. I also tried a foreach on a new column filled with 0s to fill the column row by row, but it didn't work as well.

Do you see how I can achieve this in Scala ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same result can be achieved without function, performance will be better:

```
val num = 10
df.withColumn("c", col("a") + col("b") - lit(num))
```

Version with UDF:

```
val num = 10
val f = (a: Int, b: Int) => {a + b - num}
val fUDF = udf(f)
df.withColumn("c", fUDF(col("a"), col("b")))
```

Comment: Well this was just an exemple, I really have to pass by the fuction. In a more general case where I manipulate more complex types than Int, this won't work. I use Int in my example to make it simple

Comment: Thanks for your edit, now it works fine ! I didn't thought that user defined function (UDF) could be use in that case. Thanks for the tip ;)